# Method with two arrays. If value in first array returns not null, corresponding element of other array has to be used as argument for a second method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am new to programming/java and have a short assignment due tonight that I can't figure out. Just need to be put in the right direction. Here is the what I need.

Write a method, methodOne(), which returns a value of float. It has two parameters. The first parameter is an array of integer, the second parameter is an array of String.

methodOne() examines the value of each element of the String array in order. If an element is not null, then the corresponding element in the array of integer is used as an argument in a function call to methodTwo(). methodTwo() checks the value of the argument. If it is greater than zero, then methodTwo() returns true, else it returns false.

Upon methodTwo()'s return back to methodOne(), methodOne() checks that value and if it is equal to true, continues, else it returns -1.0.

Thank you

Comment: Please show us what you have written so far, and ask specific questions about behaviour you don't understand.

Comment: So far all I have is the declaration:  float methodOne(int[]first, String[]second) {

Comment: How do I write a loop that will test the values of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should get you started. Basically you keep an index while iterating through your arrays. Based on the question I am assuming the string and the integer array both have equal size.

```
    public Integer methodOne(int[] numberArray, String[] stringArray){
    boolean check = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
        if(!stringArray[i].equals(null)) {
            check = methodTwo(numberArray[i]);
        }
    }
    if(check == false){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        return 0; //"RETURN SOMETHING ELSE HERE
    }
}

public boolean methodTwo(int number){
    return number > 0;
}
```

"return number > 0" will return true if number is greater than 0 and false otherwise